# How to hide editview when grid contains no data(in Ext.js)

Tags: extjs

I am a newbie to ext.js.I wanted to hide view panel when grid contains no data.Also I wanted to show a empty data message in that hided place.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If the table definition:

```
initComponent:function() {
    var me = this;

    me.viewConfig = {
        deferEmptyText: false,
        emptyText: notifyMessage(
            'No events',
            'In this device, there are no events in the selected period.'
        )
    };

    me.callParent(arguments);
}
```

The function returns the message layout may be such:

```
function notifyMessage (msg, lmsg, img) {
    var image = img || '/img/info.png';
    var message = msg || '';
    var little_message = lmsg || '';

    return Ext.String.format(
            '<div class="grid-data-empty">' +
                '<img src="{0}" width=100 height=100 alt="" />' +
                '<div class="empty-grid-headline">{1}</div>' +
                '<div class="empty-grid-byline">{2}</div>' +
            '</div>',
            image,
            message,
            little_message
        )
    );
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6rSn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why/whether you want to hide the grid. Have you had a look at [`emptyText`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1-classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-emptyText)? This shows an empty data message in the empty grid, without any need to program something fancy.

Comment: it wont work with emptyText because that text will show in grid.I want it to be shown at viewpanel